# "Lifting the centralizer"

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, $T\le G$ and $N\unlhd G$ with $(|N|,|T|)=1$. Clearly $T$ acts by conjugation on $G$ and $N$ is a $T$-invariant subgroup; for this reason $T$ induces naturally an action on $G/N$ in the following way:

$${(Ng)}^t:=Ng^t$$

We define $C_{G/N}(T):=\{t\in T\,:{(Ng)}^t=Ng\quad \forall Ng\in G/N \}$ and from the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem it is true the following equality (it is not an immediate consequence):

> $$C_{G/N}(T)=C_G(T)N/N$$

This is clear for me, but I've found in literature the equality (without proof)

> $$C_{G/N}(TN/N)=C_G(T)N/N$$

Now, my question is:

How can I prove the second equality? Why is $C_{G/N}(TN/N)=C_{G/N}(T)$?

Comment: I want to prove the second equality and a way to do this is showing that $C_{G/N}(TN/N)=G_{G/N}(T)$ (thanks to the result that I've cited).

Answer (score 2):

The way you've defined $C_{G/N}(T)$ isn't standard. $C_{G/N}(T)$ usually denotes the set $\{gN\in G/N: (gN)T=T(gN)\}$, which doesn't make any sense because $T$ is a subgroup of $G$, not $G/N$.  The equations you've found elsewhere in the literature use the standard definition.

Comment: Yes I know that my definition is not standard; formally  the subgroup that I called $C_{G/N}(T)$ is the set of fixed point in the action of $T$ on $G/N$. To be clear: 

$C_{G/N}(TN/N)$ and $C_G(T)$ are really centralizers in the    usual way.

$C_{G/N}(T)$ is a set of fixed point, so not really a centralizer. Maybe in the usual notation we have that $C_{G/N}(T)=fix_{G/N}(T)$.

Answer (score 2):

I find your set up a little confusing: the subgroup $T$ is naturally isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/N)$, so setting up your conjugation action of $T$ on $G/N$ need not be so complicated, and the subgroup you defined is just the centralizer in $G/N$ of the image of $T.$
  To get the identification of groups in the cited result, you use the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem and a Frattini-type argument. The preimage in $G$ of $N_{G/N}(TN/N)$ is $N_{G}(TN),$ and this clearly contains $NN_{G}(T).$ On the other hand, if $x \in N_{G}(TN),$ then $T^{x}$ is conjugate to $T$ via an an element of $N$, say $n,$ using the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem. Hence $T^{x} = T^{n}$ and $xn^{-1} \in N_{G}(T),$ so $x \in NN_{G}(T).$ 
Hence $N_{G/N}(TN/N) =N_{G}(T)N/N.$ The argument with the centralizer is similar, but taken one element at a time.

Comment: Practically, by the second isomorphism theorem $T\cong TN/N $ with the map $t\mapsto Nt$, and the action of $T$ on $G/N$ that I have defined is evidently the same as the action by conjugation of $TN/N$ on $G/N$:

$$(Nt^{-1})(Ng) (Nt)=Nt^{-1}gt=Ng^t={(Ng)}^t$$

This proves that $C_{G/N}(T)=C_{G/N}(TN/N)$